# 3 or more level nested forms Rails 4 - SImple Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested, simple-form

I need to create a form with several models, at least five. At the moment I am trying to make it work using three forms (Person - Diseases - Treatments). The second first and second level forms work correctly. The third form doesn't even render in my view. Can somebody help me with this? Thanks in advance!!!.

**Form**

```
<%= simple_form_for @person, :html => { id: "smart-form-register" , class: "smart-form client-form" } do |f| %>

    <header>
        Por favor, completa el formulario
    </header>

    <fieldset>
        <h2>Datos de contacto e información general</h2><br>
        <section>
            <label class="input">
                <%= f.input :phone, label: 'Teléfono' %>
        </section>
        <div class="row">
            <section class="col col-2">
                <%= f.input :name, :input_html => { :value => current_user.name}, :as => :hidden %>
            </section>
            <section class="col col-2">
                <%= f.input :lastname, :input_html => { :value => current_user.lastname}, :as => :hidden %>
            </section>
            <section class="col col-6">
                <%= f.input :email, :input_html => { :value => current_user.email}, :as => :hidden %>
            </section>
        </div>
    </fieldset>

        <%= f.simple_fields_for :diseases do |my_disease| %>

            <fieldset>
                <h2>¿Padeces alguna enfermedad?</h2><br>
                <section>
                    <label class="input">
                        <%= my_disease.input :name, label: 'Nombre de la enfermedad' %>
                </section>
                <div class="row">
                    <section class="col col-6">
                        <%= my_disease.input :start, :as => :date_picker, label: 'Inicio de la enfermedad' %>
                    </section>
                    <section class="col col-6">
                        <%= my_disease.input :end, :as => :date_picker, label: 'Fin de la enfermedad' %>
                    </section>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <section class="col col-6">
                        <%= my_disease.input :chronical, as: :boolean, :html => {type: "checkbox" }, label: false, inline_label: 'Enfermedad crónica' %>
                    </section>
                    <section class="col col-6">
                    <span class="">
                        <%= my_disease.input :unfinished, as: :boolean, :html => {type: "checkbox" }, label: false, inline_label: 'Enfermedad actual' %>
                    </span>
                    </section>
                </div>
                <section>
                            <%= my_disease.input :description, label: 'Descripción de la enfermedad' %>
                </section>
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>
                <section>
                        <%= my_disease.simple_fields_for :treatments do |my_treatment| %>
                                <%= my_treatment.input :name, label: 'Nombre del tratamiento' %>
                        <% end %>
                </section>                      
            </fieldset>

        <% end %>

    <footer><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button></footer>

<% end %>
```

**Person Controller**

```
def person_params
  params.require(:person).permit(:name, :surname, :gender, :birthdate, :bloodtype, :user_id, :phone, :email, diseases_attributes: [:id, :name, :description, :start, :end, :chronical, :description, :unfinished, treatments_attributes: [:id, :name]] )
end
```

**Diseases Controller**

```
def disease_params
  params.require(:disease).permit(:name, :start, :end, :chronical, :unfinished, :description, :person_id, :person_id, treatments_attributes: [:id, :name] )
end
```

**Diseases Model**

```
class Disease < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  has_many :treatments
  # validates_presence_of :name, :start
  # validates :name, :length => {:maximum => 50, :too_long => "is too long, you can use the description field"}
  # validate :start_must_be_before_end, :unless => [:chronical, :unfinished], :presence => true
  # validates :end, :presence => true, :unless => [:chronical, :unfinished], :presence => true
  # validates :description, :length => {:maximum => 5000, :too_long => "is too long"}

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :treatments

  def start_must_be_before_end
    if self[:end] < self[:start]
      errors.add(:start, "must be before end time")
      return false
    else
      return true
    end
  end

end
```

**Person Model**

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :user
      has_many :diseases, :dependent => :destroy #if you delete a person you also delete all diseases related
      has_many :appointments, :dependent => :destroy
      has_many :treatments, through: :diseases
      validates_presence_of :name, :email
      validates :name, :length => {:maximum => 50, :too_long => "name is too long"}
      VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
      validates :email, format: { :with => VALID_EMAIL_REGEX , message: "is invalid" }

      accepts_nested_attributes_for :diseases
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :treatments

    end
```

**Terminal**

```
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 60 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Unpermitted parameters: treatments
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "people" ("created_at", "email", "name", "phone", "surname", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Fri, 13 Jun 2014 14:17:12 UTC +00:00], ["email", "danielcastillomarfull@gmail.com"], ["name", "Daniel"], ["phone", "123123"], ["surname", "Castillo"], ["updated_at", Fri, 13 Jun 2014 14:17:12 UTC +00:00], ["user_id", 60]]
  SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "diseases" ("chronical", "created_at", "description", "end", "name", "person_id", "start", "unfinished", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9) RETURNING "id"  [["chronical", false], ["created_at", Fri, 13 Jun 2014 14:17:12 UTC +00:00], ["description", ""], ["end", Fri, 13 Jun 2014], ["name", "desidia"], ["person_id", 161], ["start", Thu, 12 Jun 2014], ["unfinished", false], ["updated_at", Fri, 13 Jun 2014 14:17:12 UTC +00:00]]
   (51.7ms)  COMMIT
```

Comment: Can you post your person model?

Comment: May be you should add `has_many :treatments, through: :diseases` to your person model

Comment: Only that? Do I should change any other thing in my models? I already try your suggestion but still doesn't work. Thanks for your help, Pavan

Comment: You also need to add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :treatments` to the Person model.

Comment: The same, sorry... :-( I include the terminal. Says something about Unpermitted parameters: treatments (0.2ms)

Comment: @user3402629 Use `<%= my_disease.simple_fields_for :treatments, my_disease.object.treatments.build do |my_treatment| %>`

Comment: Uf! Finally! I did it. Thaks everybody for your precious support. I followed the suggestion of Kirti. Also, there was a incorrect validation in my Treatment model. By the way, I included accepts_nested_attributes_for :treatments not in the Person model, but in the Disease model.

Comment: Post it as answer,so it may helpful to someone.

Answer (score 0):

Have you test to add

```
:treatments
```

to

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for
```

in

```
class Person
```

Comment: I already tryied but... No association found for name `treatments'. Has it been defined yet?

Comment: In that case there are not association errors but the form still don't work

Answer (score 0):

finally I made it as follows:

**Form**

```
<%= simple_form_for @person, :html => { id: "smart-form-register" , class: "smart-form client-form" } do |f| %>

    <header>
        Por favor, completa el formulario
    </header>

    <fieldset>
        <h2>Datos de contacto e información general</h2><br>
        <section>
            <label class="input">
                <%= f.input :phone, label: 'Teléfono' %>
        </section>
        <div class="row">
            <section class="col col-2">
                <%= f.input :name, :input_html => { :value => current_user.name}, :as => :hidden %>
            </section>
            <section class="col col-2">
                <%= f.input :surname, :input_html => { :value => current_user.lastname}, :as => :hidden %>
            </section>
            <section class="col col-6">
                <%= f.input :email, :input_html => { :value => current_user.email}, :as => :hidden %>
            </section>
        </div>
    </fieldset>

        <%= f.simple_fields_for :diseases do |my_disease| %>
            <fieldset>
                <h2>¿Padeces alguna enfermedad?</h2><br>
                <section>
                    <label class="input">
                        <%= my_disease.input :name, label: 'Nombre de la enfermedad' %>
                </section>
                <div class="row">
                    <section class="col col-6">
                        <%= my_disease.input :start, :as => :date_picker, label: 'Inicio de la enfermedad' %>
                    </section>
                    <section class="col col-6">
                        <%= my_disease.input :end, :as => :date_picker, label: 'Fin de la enfermedad' %>
                    </section>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <section class="col col-6">
                        <%= my_disease.input :chronical, as: :boolean, :html => {type: "checkbox" }, label: false, inline_label: 'Enfermedad crónica' %>
                    </section>
                    <section class="col col-6">
                    <span class="">
                        <%= my_disease.input :unfinished, as: :boolean, :html => {type: "checkbox" }, label: false, inline_label: 'Enfermedad actual' %>
                    </span>
                    </section>
                </div>
                <section>
                            <%= my_disease.input :description, label: 'Descripción de la enfermedad' %>
                </section>
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>
                <section>
                        <%= my_disease.simple_fields_for :treatments, my_disease.object.treatments.build do |my_treatment| %>
                                <%= my_treatment.input :name, label: 'Nombre del tratamiento' %>
                        <% end %>
                </section>                      
            </fieldset>

        <% end %>

    <footer><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button></footer>

<% end %>
```

**Person model**

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :user
      has_many :diseases, :dependent => :destroy #if you delete a person you also delete all diseases related
      has_many :appointments, :dependent => :destroy

      validates_presence_of :name, :email
  #    validates :name, :length => {:maximum => 50, :too_long => "name is too long"}
  #    VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  #    validates :email, format: { :with => VALID_EMAIL_REGEX , message: "is invalid" }

      accepts_nested_attributes_for :diseases


    end
```

**Disease model**

```
class Disease < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  has_many :treatments
  # validates_presence_of :name, :start
  # validates :name, :length => {:maximum => 50, :too_long => "is too long, you can use the description field"}
  # validate :start_must_be_before_end, :unless => [:chronical, :unfinished], :presence => true
  # validates :end, :presence => true, :unless => [:chronical, :unfinished], :presence => true
  # validates :description, :length => {:maximum => 5000, :too_long => "is too long"}
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :treatments

  def start_must_be_before_end
    if self[:end] < self[:start]
      errors.add(:start, "must be before end time")
      return false
    else
      return true
    end
  end

end
```

**Treatment model**

```
class Treatment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :disease
  has_many :medicines
  # validates_presence_of :name, :start
  # validates :days, :allow_blank => true, :numericality => { :greater_than_or_equal_to => 1, :message => ": leave this field blank or enter a positive number" }
  # validates :name, :length => {:maximum => 50, :too_long => "is too long, you can use the description field"}
  # validates :description, :length => {:maximum => 5000, :too_long => "is too long"}
end
```

Comment: can you please paste your strong parameters from controller for this? I do have same problem.

Comment: can you show your new and create method from controller?